# ramification locus for finite morphism and Abhyankar's Lemma

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, singularity-theory

I want to ask given a finite morphism between projective varieties $f:X\rightarrow Y$.
What is exactly the ramification locus $\Delta(X/Y)$. If $X$, $Y$, $f$ are smooth, then I can more or less understand it.

Q1: There should be strict definition of $\Delta(X/Y)$ (Any reference?). Also, is there a good example to see $\Delta(X/Y)$ ***with $X,Y$ singular*** variety.

Q2: I saw a theorem, which says that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is finite morphism,$X$ normal, $Y$ smooth and $\Delta(X/Y)$ simple normal crossing, then $X$ has quotient singularity. The proof is refered to  Abhyankar's Lemma (in Germany), I wonder how the Abhyankar's Lemma can be applied here. Can I get a rough explanation! (Reference in English is also helpful)
Thanks!

Comment: The ramification locus is just the support of the sheaf $\Omega_{X/Y}$ on $X$. This is in [many texts](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02G4). To get examples with $X,Y$ singular, all you need to do is to compute what $\Omega_{X/Y}$ for a map of singular varieties $X\to Y$ and see where it's supported.